# Togglebutton is toggled on collection refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid showing Jobs like this:

[image]

Now I got some `BackgroundTasks` to periodically refresh the data.

When I refresh the first row is automatically toggled.

I cannot figure out why...

This is my `xaml`:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=JobCollectionView}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedEntry,
                                 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                 Mode=TwoWay}"
          IsReadOnly="True"                      
          x:Name="dataGrid"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False"              
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          CanUserResizeColumns="True"                      
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
[...]>
<DataGridTemplateColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridNonFocusableCell}">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow},
                                        Path=DetailsVisibility,
                                        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter},
                                        Mode=TwoWay,
                                        FallbackValue=False}"
                    Height="20" 
                    Width="20" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
[...]/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear why a `RelativeSource` binding is needed for a row's cell template and could it be always getting *row 1* for all its data needs regardless of the actual row.(?)

The row's datacontext should hold the actual reference to the item needed.

Remove the `RelativeSource` binding in favor of just a direct to inherited datacontext binding of the object.

If that doesn't work, break out your situation into a demo-able example (which you could post here instead) reproducing the situation. Creating the demo may help you sort through why there is a failure.